# bxSlider Image resizing issue

Tags: bxslider

I am implementing bxslider into my page and it works pretty well.  When I resize the page in IE, the picture resizes just fine, however if I go from a small window and hit the maximize button, the image remains small until I refresh the page.  Any idea how to get the image to expand upon pressing the maximize button??? Here's my code:

```
var announcements = $('#announcements').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        auto: true,
        controls: false,
        pause: 7000,
        prevText: '<img 
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        announcements.reloadShow();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the current version of bxSlider, the function is not reloadShow(). but it use **reloadSlider()**. http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider